# How do I avoid my printed pages tracking me?

Tags: printer

This [BBC article](https://getpocket.com/explore/item/why-printers-add-secret-tracking-dots) documents how some printers [secretly print faint dots](https://blog.erratasec.com/2017/06/how-intercept-outed-reality-winner.html) which [identify the printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Identification_Code) as well as the date and time a page is printed.

How do I choose a printer which won't do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't buy or use a color laser printer. The [EFF has been advised](https://www.eff.org/pages/list-printers-which-do-or-do-not-display-tracking-dots) "all major manufacturers of color laser printers entered a secret agreement with governments to ensure that the output of those printers is forensically traceable".

Comment: Or remove/hide the dot patterns: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/app-masks-hidden-printer-tracking-dots-to-keep-whistleblowers-safe/

Comment: I don't think I have any White-Out(TM) to remove them from the printed page.

Comment: At this point, I am no longer sure if you are joking, or intentionally misunderstanding my messages.

Comment: My original question referred to the output of a printer.